# How to find Oracle's SID Password?

Tags: database, oracle, passwords

I installed Oracle 11g on my system few months back.
At the time of installation, i set the SID's name as **admin** but I cannot remember the password that I set up for my database.

I'm posting a link of the screen where we are supposed to provide for a database password at the time of installation. This is the password I forgot.

http://static.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/1-new-select-installation-method.jpg

Now i want to use Oracle Enterprise Manager but I need this password.

Is there any way to find or reset this password?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you still are logged in with the same OS user you used to install Oracle, you can log in via SQL plus like this:

sqlplus / as sysdba

Then you can reset the password for your user:

```
ALTER USER admin IDENTIFIED BY <<password>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the user password with command

```
ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```

For example

```
ALTER USER admin  IDENTIFIED BY xxxxx;
```

You must have the `ALTER USER` system privilege.

However, you can change your own password without this privilege.